# Im using Pickle but I need to be using a textfile

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, pickle

I've made a program with Python 3 that saves the the previous run using pickle. But instead I need to be using a .txt file. As I understand it can be done with the open and .write command? But im not quite sure just how to do it. The program works fine with pickle but I have to learn how to use a text file instead. I would greatly appreciate any help!
This is the functions module which saves info after each run:

```
    import pickle
class TV(object):
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    try:
        self.load()
    except:
        self.Kanal = 1
        self.Volym = 1




def __str__(self):
    printstring = str("\n".join(("%s:","Kanal:    %s", "Volym:    %s"))%(self.name, self.Kanal, self.Volym))
    return printstring


def bytKanal(self,kanal):
    self.Kanal = kanal
    self.save()
    return kanal

def sank_volym(self):
    if self.Volym!=0:
        self.Volym -= 1
    self.save()
    return self.Volym

def hoj_volym(self):
    if self.Volym!=10:
        self.Volym += 1
    self.save()
    return self.Volym

def save(self):
    file = open(self.name+".txt","wb")
    file.write(pickle.dumps(self.__dict__))
    file.close()

def load(self):
    file = open(self.name+".txt","rb")
    datapickle = file.read()
    file.close()

    self.__dict__=pickle.loads(datapickle)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you only serialize the instance **dict** I would recommend json

```
def save(self):
    with open(self.name+".txt","w") as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(self.__dict__)) #json


def load(self):
    with open(self.name+".txt","r") as file:
        json_data = file.read()

    self.__dict__=json.loads(json_data) #json!
```

You may also want to read about json: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON